# - Child Parent bones are attached to objects on both sides of mirror? How to fix to only apply to one side?

Tags: bones, mirror, parent

[image]- Bones attached to one side of the mirror control and warp objects on the other side of the mirror? How to fix please if anyone knows?

Comment: Is the mirror a modifier or hard edited, and what's it on? In the answer below I'm guessing it's a modifier on the armature, because I had a similar problem before. :) Just remember to tell about details: it helps me help you help us all. :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply, your vertex groups (which attatch the armature) are copying to the other side of the mesh, so both the left and right arm are in the same group: The mirror mesh modifier, as far as I remember at the moment, does not automatically split and mirror vertex groups. Check that the "vertex groups" option is checked, and if it is, this is a bug.